# For loop counter returning null?

Tags: objective-c, for-loop

I'm doing a class that will handle digit by digit arithmetic (i.e. arithmetic for numbers of any size).

I have this for loop which crashes on runtime, and complains that "column" is null. Can anyone shed some light on this?

```
for(column=0; column < bigger.length; column++) {
    NSLog(@"column %@", column);
    workingDigit = [y intAt:column] + [self intAt:column] + carry;
    carry = workingDigit / 10;      //make the carry not include the last digit of the sum
    workingDigit = workingDigit % 10;      //make the digit not include the carry

    [result insertString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", workingDigit] atIndex:0];
}
```

btw column is an int, declared as an instance variable. Also, that NSLog prints out "column (null)"

Comment: `NSLog(@"column %@", column);`
  should be  `NSLog(@"column %d", column);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use this:

```
NSLog(@"column %d", column);
```